# Find one word of a list in files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a textfile with a list of words. I'm searching for an Unix solution like as follows:

For every word I want to search in all files of a directory if the word is in the file and give back the filename if the word can be found. The files are located in subdirectories of the directory.

Do I need a loop? Or is there a special command which can do that? I have found the "comm" command but it seems to work only for two files and not for the whole folder.

Comment: in your input file, is there one line per word?

Comment: yes, one line per word

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
find -type f -exec grep -H -f list_of_words.txt {} \;
```

must fulfills your needs.

The `-f` grep option makes grep check all word in list_of_words.txt for its search:

> grep --help
>
> -f, --file=FILE           take PATTERNS from FILE

The `type -f` find option tells `find` to only check files.

---

A refinement would be, by example, to search only in `*.txt` files and  also ignore your word list file `list_of_words.txt` :

```
find -type f \( -name \*.txt ! -name list_of_words.txt \) -exec grep -H -f list_of_words.txt {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the files to be searched are in the same folder and not within any sub folders within it, below will do

```
ls -p | grep -v / | xargs grep -lf <file_with_list_of_words>
```

Comment: No, there are subfolders, I added this to the question